# Tooling api problem

Tags: tooling-api

```
Public class testapi{
   ToolingAPI toolingAPI = new ToolingAPI();
   List<ToolingAPI.CustomObject> customObjects = (List<ToolingAPI.CustomObject>) toolingAPI.query(
   'Select Id, DeveloperName, NamespacePrefix From'+
   'CustomObject Where NamespacePrefix = \'c\''
   ).records;
}
```

I am not able to save this code it is coming :

> Invalid type: ToolingAPI

kindly help me to resolve the issue

Comment: I am not able to see ToolingAPI object definition anywhere in Salesforce developer documentation.  Is it coming from some other Managed package which you missed to install ? or Please point me to the documenation you are referring

Comment: I am referring some blogs and try to create it.http://andyinthecloud.com/category/tooling-api/

Comment: whether i need to use rest callout to implement this code or we can directly in the apex

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer:** https://githubsfdeploy.herokuapp.com/?owner=afawcett&repo=apex-toolingapi

**Long Answer:**

You are missing the required Package https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi. This is the package which contains the `ToolingAPI` class.

- Go to this page https://githubsfdeploy.herokuapp.com/?owner=afawcett&repo=apex-toolingapi
- Click `login into salesforce` button
- Login with your Salesforce credentials and install it to your org
- Click `deploy` when it shows all the `src/..` files below
- Confirm that installation of the package is complete and try saving the above code again.

**Ref:**

https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi

**Update:**

I tried all the steps above in my org and finally tried your snippet and it works fine.